# List won't serialize with protobuf

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am experimenting with using protobuf-net for an upcoming project but I am having a hard time figuring out how to serialize lists of a class. I have created a dotnet fiddle to test out some basic scenarios and everything works until I create a simple class and add a list of that class to another class to be serialized. I create an instance of my class and print it to show all the values, then serialize, deserialize and print again to show that all the data made it through the process but my list keeps coming back empty. Anyone know whats going on here?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var item = new MyClass();
        var listItem1 = new ComplexList();
        listItem1.pubField = "first one";
        var listItem2 = new ComplexList();
        listItem2.pubField = "second one";
        item.ComplexList.Add(listItem1);
        item.ComplexList.Add(listItem2);
        item.Print();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        var serialized = ProtoObjectToByteArray(item);
        var deserialized = ProtoByteArrayToObject<MyClass>(serialized);
        deserialized.Print();
    }

    public static byte[] ProtoObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
            return null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static T ProtoByteArrayToObject<T>(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        if(arrBytes == null)
            return default(T);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrBytes))
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ms);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class ComplexList {
    public string pubField;

    public ComplexList(){}
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class MyClass {  
    public List<ComplexList> ComplexList { get; set; }

    public MyClass(){
        ComplexList = new List<ComplexList>();
    }

    public void Print(){
        foreach(var x in ComplexList){
            Console.WriteLine(x.pubField);
        }
    }
}
```

Updated as requested
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vnfMWh

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (where the code is in the question, not behind an external link).

Comment: I updated my post as you requested with minimal code to reproduce my issue. The pubFields work as expected so don't worry about those. That project was created purely to test various scenarios and see where I had issues serializing and deserializing. So far everything works like I expect except lists of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protobuf-net wants you to annotate your type:

```
[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class ComplexList {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string pubField;

    public ComplexList(){}
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class MyClass {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<ComplexList> ComplexList { get; set; }

    public MyClass(){
        ComplexList = new List<ComplexList>();
    }

    public void Print(){
        foreach(var x in ComplexList){
            Console.WriteLine(x.pubField);
        }
    }
}
```

Fields in protobuf are given numeric identifiers and it wants a reliable way of knowing which field is which number.

Note that you don't need `[Serializable]` for protobuf-net.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought to try that because everything else was working without the attribute until I added that property.